# What's the best way to deal with "not found" cases on PHP magic methods?

Tags: php, error-handling, metaprogramming, magic-methods

Sometimes you're using PHP magic methods to allow access to only some specific properties/methods, and don't want to disclose the usage of magic methods for that in error cases.

Examples:

- `__get` or `__set` that only access a subset of properties instead of arbitrary names
- `__call` or `__callStatic` that search for specific methods or simplify some calls, instead of forwarding arbitrary calls somewhere else

Is it possible to send the request back to PHP to handle, issuing the appropriate error message?
If not, what's the best way to simulate the original PHP "not found" error?

**The idea is to hide the implementation detail that I'm using a magic method to allow read of specific `protected` properties, and make the object behave the standard way, as if there was no such property. The same idea applies to other cases such as magic `__set()` and `__call()`.**

Comment: Use [`trigger_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php).

Comment: yep, but that's still traceable as coming from user code, as the best we can do is trigger a E_USER_NOTICE, different from the internal E_NOTICE.

Comment: As long as a *useful* error is triggered it should hardly matter whether it is "native" or userland code. For what purpose are you trying to hide your implementation to the extend that you want to fake native errors? Anyone interested enough can easily inspect the implementation details anyway.

Comment: but anyone not interested should not have the attention drawn to an "odd standard error". the object should just behave like a normal object that doesn't have the magic method, that's used to open read access to a couple of protected properties only. why is that something bad to request?

Comment: edited the question adding further explanation of the intentions

Answer (score 0):

By now, it seems the best behavior for getters/setters is using `trigger_error()`, although not yet what was desired since it's still traceable as being some error/protection coming from user code: there's no way to trigger a pure Notice, only User Notice:

```
public function __get($name) {
    if (in_array($name, $this->allowed_fields)) {
        return $this->$name;
    } else {
        trigger_error('Undefined property: '.static::class."::\$$name", E_USER_NOTICE);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why is this a requirement: _still traceable as being some error/protection coming from user code:_

Comment: because I don't need to disclose those properties came from a magic getter. That's just an implementation detail, from the class API point of view.

Comment: why are you asking that? that library has no special exceptions.

Comment: I don't tend to see a lot of raw PHP errors and notices these days. What I tend to see is throwing and catching exceptions, which can be handled where the user doesn't see the implementation detail. So I was wondering if you were up to anything specific with how you were handling your errors. Neither here nor there.

Comment: I think what you want is this: [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) That appears to allow you to get around the `E_USER` bit.

Comment: not sure I follow, Jared. `set_error_handler()` is used to write... custom error handlers. That still doesn't allow me to emulate the original behavior.

Comment: Exceptions are also not useful because that's different from the standard behavior when the object has no magic getter.